# Summary of a Column (Achieving a Cube Function on Spark Dataset)

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, rdd, apache-spark-dataset

For below Dataset I need to get a Summary Data based on Selected Column The sample Dataset contains Following Below Data.

```
+---------+----------+--------+---------+
| Column1 | Column2  | Expend | Expend2 |
+---------+----------+--------+---------+
| School1 | Student1 | 5      | 10      |
+---------+----------+--------+---------+
| School1 | Student2 | 11     | 12      |
+---------+----------+--------+---------+
| School2 | Student1 | 6      | 8       |
+---------+----------+--------+---------+
| School2 | Student2 | 7      | 8       |
+---------+----------+--------+---------+
```

I need to get Summary Data for Column2 as below,

**Required Format**

```
+---------+----------+--------+---------+
| Column1 | Column2  | Expend | Expend2 |
+---------+----------+--------+---------+
| School1 | Total    | 16     | 22      |
+---------+----------+--------+---------+
| School1 | Student1 | 5      | 10      |
+---------+----------+--------+---------+
| School1 | Student2 | 11     | 12      |
+---------+----------+--------+---------+
| School2 | Total    | 13     | 16      |
+---------+----------+--------+---------+
| School2 | Student1 | 6      | 8       |
+---------+----------+--------+---------+
| School2 | Student2 | 7      | 8       |
+---------+----------+--------+---------+
```

I tried using cube function on dataset but that didn't give me expected results. 
I get `null` values in place of `Total` which is also okay, but the data I dont get in above format.

I wanted to try using `dataset.cube("Column2").agg(sum("Expend1"),sum("Expend2"))`;

But this above line of code gives me only data for Column2 , How Can I retrieve Column1 values with above return data.

Comment: what have you tried Gary ? the answer seems easy do group aggreration and find totals for each groups and save it in a new dataframe and merge old with new dataframe . You should be done

Comment: @RameshMaharjan I tried dataset.cube(Column2)  Since I need only  summary of Column 2 but It erases column 1 I need Column1 too

Comment: Could you please give a sample headsup for above format, for above Dataset

Comment: you are using java right? I am a bit weak on java spark. :(

Comment: u can try in spark , I can then rewrite same in Java.

Comment: I can write in scala. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From your existing `dataframe` you can create a *total dataframe* where you `groupBy` *Column1* and *sum all the Expend columns* as

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._
val totaldf = df.groupBy("Column1").agg(lit("Total").as("Column2"), sum("Expend").as("Expend"), sum("Expend2").as("Expend2"))
```

Then you just `merge` them

```
df.union(totaldf).orderBy(col("Column1"), col("Column2").desc).show(false)
```

You should have your desired output

```
+-------+--------+------+-------+
|Column1|Column2 |Expend|Expend2|
+-------+--------+------+-------+
|School1|Total   |16.0  |22.0   |
|School1|Student2|11    |12     |
|School1|Student1|5     |10     |
|School2|Total   |13.0  |16.0   |
|School2|Student2|7     |8      |
|School2|Student1|6     |8      |
+-------+--------+------+-------+
```

Comment: Thanks Ramesh , How can I get Totals At the Top.

Comment: you can order column2 in desc :) the answer is updated ;)

Comment: @GarrySteve, isn't [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49105568/getting-the-summary-of-whole-dataset-or-only-columns-in-apache-spark-java/49105666#49105666) question and extension of this one. it yes then would you mind considering accepting this answer?

Answer (score 0):

```
from pyspark.sql import functions as F

df_cube = df.cube("Column1","Column2").agg(F.sum("Expend").alias("Expend"),F.sum("Expend2").alias("Expend2"))
```

This will return the expected result where you will get NULL instead of Total and you can convert that in next step